# return specific index from 3D numpy array into 1D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've a 3D array that I need to recover the data corresponding to one specific index from an specifique axis.

```
x_train.shape
Out[101]: (990, 19, 3)

x_train[:,0,:]
Out[117]: 
array([[0.08581368, 0.09640129, 0.09044931],
       [0.09701243, 0.09834351, 0.09823458],
       [0.09433366, 0.09251685, 0.09408623],
       ...,
       [0.88172483, 0.9100043 , 0.89555236],
       [0.90901481, 0.9104525 , 0.90519397],
       [0.89063546, 0.90311315, 0.90350811]])
```

I need to get only the index 0 from this array

```
0.08581368,
0.09701243,
0.09433366,
...,
0.90901481,
0.89063546
```

I've tried splitting the array with 
my_new_array = np.split(x_train, 990, axis=0)
but I get a list (990) and for each record I 've a type array (1,19,13)

It doesn't fix my problem.

I've checked some solutions right here in stack, besides this solution
comes from here, but there's something I don't get, and I really appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first *index* would be `x_train[:, 0, :][0]` which is directly accessed via

```
x_train[0, 0, :]
```

which is the first *row* - but this is not what you want.

Your example looks like the first *column*, and this can be accessed by

```
x_train[:, 0, 0]
```

Comment: x_train[0,0,:]
Out[122]: array([0.08581368, 0.09640129, 0.09044931])  I get the first line from the panel

Comment: Hi, please expand on your answer as to why this would be a solution to OP's issue. This will help OP and future visitors of the site. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, which is the first index of the underlying 2D-array, check it via `x_train[:, 0, :][0]`... However, I didn't read your question carefully enough and oversaw your requested output example,  sorry.  However,  IMO, this would be the first _column_ in opposite of the first _row_ - anyway, please see my edit...

Comment: You're right. with x_train[:, 0, 0]  we get the expected results. One zero sets the dimension where we want the data from, and the second zero, the index from that "panel". Thank you for your help